# WPF: DataGrid Custom. ColumnDesign with my own classes

Tags: datagrid

I am looking for a datagrid which contains objects from my class.

```
class user
{
string name;
int ID;
...
}
```

i tried **AutoGenerateColumns = true**. this will add columns (name, ID, ... like the properties of my class)
but i want a different design. not all attributes from the object shold be shown and the columnheader shouldn't be generated from the variablenames...

if i build a custom. column-design, i cant add my objects / they will not be displayed.

is it possible to define my own columns according to my objects/class.
i read about databindings, but i have no idea how i can bind objects/classes in WPF.
(in Visual Studio i cant choose my class as datacontext)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define your own columns by using **DataGridTemplateColumn** and making AutoGenerateColumns = false.

Then you can hook in DataTemplate to this DatGridTemplatecolumn to display the object the way you want.

Please search in internet regarding **DataGridTemplateColumn**. You will find all the info you need.
Hope I am clear.

Comment: thank you. <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nickname" Binding="{Binding UserName}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns> worked out. I thought you have to do more for the databinding :-)